# Compiler actively reducing compile errors in code?

Tags: compiler-construction, analysis, autocorrect

I was sitting in beginning Computer Science class this week and thought of something:

Is there a compiler that actively corrects compile errors that arise in code (effectively a feedback loop of reducing/eliminating errors in code)?

This is done passively with suggestions (e.g. red underlining on unknown syntax, auto-completion when typing in code) in some programming environments, but are there examples of a compiler doing this actively (i.e. directly rewriting the code)?

Thinking about this lead me to think about something else:

How complex would this be to implement? I imagine extremely complex, as it comes down to analyzing the code and balancing precision (e.g. pinpointing exactly what a user wants- asking questions and getting programmer feedback) with convenient generality (e.g. deciding "generally" what the user wants and making changes to the code- the programmer could then go back in and alter the code to be more specific to their task ). These are rough ideas, as a highly complex, focused program involves many, many complex ideas whose priorities are not always easily detected in the code (and easily analyzable).

As an extreme example a syntax-free piece of code such as "draw a rectangle" could be analyzed and then with programmer input (getting feedback from the programmer on questions such as "draw where?", "what size rectangle?", or "2d or 3d space?") a program could be written (privileging precision over generality). Or there could be low level default values which are used to create code when keywords ("draw", "rectangle") are spotted (privileging generality over precision).

Comment: Sounds like you're taking about an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: Yes- it would have to be an IDE for the loop to be present, I suppose.

Comment: I wouldn't want my compiler to actively rewrite code. Loss of control. Possibility of the compiler trying to be too clever and making the wrong choices. There are probably always several different ways to fix an error, and I would not trust the compiler to be able to figure it out. A "feedback loop" is provided already by an IDE, which can show compile errors and propose fixes (that the user has to then accept).

Comment: But what if the programmer prefers help over control (i.e. is new to programming/is a younger person)? I think that was the kind of programmer I was thinking an IDE that had a more "hands on" approach would be aimed at.

Comment: A IDE that *suggests* a correction would be ok (and I think some of them do so).  Making the correction in response to, say, a mouse click could be handy.  Making a correction without explicit permission is not something I'd want a development system to do.

Comment: @Thilo and what if compiler asked you about proposed fix each time? Adding missing semicolon or fixing misspelled method name wouldn't require launching the compilation process again - only doing on-the-fly change.

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers attempt some level of syntax repair while parsing, but only so they don't report 100 syntax errors against one fault. However guessing what the programmer intended and giving them a working executable program after such a process is fraught with danger.

Answer (score 0):

It was done in 1973.  Several Cornell University CS researchers designed a compiler for the [PL/I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I) language called [PL/C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/C).  It was intended as a teaching system, and compiled **every** program to something that was syntactically correct and could be compiled and executed.  It would repetitively rewrite or remove invalid statements until they would compile correctly.  A later, more-IDE-like version of their work is described in a [1977 technical report](http://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/7028/1/77-301.pdf).

Comment: Very fascinating- thank you very much, Ross! I will study the report and see how they handled it.